# many-to-many checkboxes not checked when they should be

Tags: symfony

I have a form with a bunch of many-to-many checkboxes. The form *saves* just fine (I checked the database to make sure), but then the checkboxes aren't *checked* in agreement with the database.

Is there something special I need to do to get the checkboxes to stay checked?

Here's my form definition:

```
<?php

namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class PreferencesSportsICareAboutType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder->add('interestingSports', 'entity', array(
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true,
            'property'      => 'name',
            'class'         => 'VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\Sport',
            'query_builder' => function(\VNN\PressboxBundle\Repository\SportRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
            },  
        )); 
    }   

    public function getName()
    {   
        return 'vnn_pressboxbundle_preferencessportsicareabouttype';
    }   
}
```

And here's the relevant part of my template:

```
{% block form %}
    <h2>Sports I Care About</h2>
    <form action="{{ path('user_update_preferences', { 'sectionName': sectionName }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} novalidate class="clearfix">

        {% for error in errors %}
            error: {{ error.messageTemplate }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.interestingSports %}
           <li>
             {{ form_widget(field) }}
             {{ form_label(field) }}
           </li>
        {% endfor %}

        {{ form_rest(form) }}

        <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: There is nothing special you should add to let your checkboxes status be in agreement with your database. It your relations are defined well. This should perfectly work with the code you posted.

Comment: Okay, so in other words, maybe it's a problem with how my entity relationships are specified?

Comment: I think it is. Because I have the same code snippet and it's working fine.

Comment: Woud you be kind enough to put your code (particularly the entity relationships) in a pastebin so I could compare mine to yours?

Comment: *Update* Find [here](https://gist.github.com/4144126) a full example from my own code (which is working fine) that have the same behavior than what you're trying to do. Except that it's for a one-to-may relationship.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't think that helps me much. My problem seems to be specifically a many-to-many issue.

Comment: Ahmed, I figured it out. If you'd like to put as an answer that it's probably a problem with the entity relationships, I'll accept it and update your answer with my specific issue.

Comment: Thanks, I added the answer and I'm really interesting to know what was going wrong in your entity relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Type and your Template are well defined. You should check your entity relationships.

I have already implement the [same behavior](https://gist.github.com/4144126) but using a One-To-Many relationship.

**Edit by OP:**

It was the entity relationships. I needed to change this

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserSportInterest", inversedBy="sports")
 * @JoinTable(name="user_sport_interest",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="sport_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $sports;
```

to this (note `targetEntity` change)

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sport", inversedBy="sports")
 * @JoinTable(name="user_sport_interest",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="sport_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $sports;
```

After that, it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't your relationship a one-to-many as opposed to many-to-many? A Room has many Workstations? That's one difference that may be significant.